# Get Renderer Info using React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm looking for a way to call `renderer.info` using r3f. [ThreeJS Doc - WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer)

As this is an older project I'm still using the class component here to call the render method.

```
 return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Canvas >
    </ Canvas>
```

I need to check my render calls to optimize performance.
Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

according to [official r3f doc about hooks](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/API/hooks), `useThree().gl` is equivalent to `WebGLRenderer`.

```
import { useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const GetInfo = () => {
  const { gl } = useThree();
  useEffect(() => {
    // gl === WebGLRenderer
    // gl.info.calls
    console.log(gl.info);
  });
  return null;
};

export default GetInfo;
```

here is working code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-violet-8hqjz?file=/src/GetInfo.tsx

Comment: thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for.